# How to raw query with datetime in SqlAlchemy Python3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I am trying to query from a table `messages` on the basis of a datetime field `timeStamp` but I keep getting an error. Maybe the way I am trying to query is not correct.

```
def get_test(self, start_date, end_date):
        
        query = 'SELECT * from messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > {start_date} and messages."timeStamp" < {end_date};'
        res = self.session.execute(query)
        self.session.commit()
        
        return res.fetchall()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "00"
LINE 1: ... messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > 2021-06-01 00:00:00 a...
```

I also tried using `datetime.strptime` method but that didn't work too.

```
def get_test(self, start_date, end_date):
        
        query = f'''SELECT * from messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > {datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}   
        and messages."timeStamp" < {datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")};'''
        res = self.session.execute(query)
        self.session.commit()
        
        return res.fetchall()
```

I also tried using the query parameters but that didn't work either.

```
 def get_test(self, start_date, end_date):
        
        query = f'SELECT * from messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > %s and messages."timeStamp" < %s;'
        res = self.session.execute(query, (datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                                           datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
        self.session.commit()
        
        return res.fetchall()
```

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things going on here.

I don't think your f-strings are populating and strptime is for turning strings into dates, not the other way round.

I'd write it like this:

```
query = f'SELECT * from messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > {start_date.isoformat()} and messages."timeStamp" < {end_date.isoformat()};'
```

Comment: So my date variables are of str type (e.g. '2021-01-01 00:00:00'), so I cannot use `isofortmat` on a string. If I convert the date variables to datetime and use the isoformat in the query it gives the following error.
```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "T00"
LINE 1: ...m messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > 2021-06-01T00:00:00 ...

```

Comment: I see what's going on now. Thanks for the clarification.

Your date string needs to be in single quotes like this:

`query = f'SELECT * from messages WHERE messages."timeStamp" > \'{start_date}\' and messages."timeStamp" < \'{end_date}\';`